# Connect nodejs (local) to cassandra database running on docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, cassandra

I have a nodejs API running locally and I would like to connect it to my cassandra cluster running on a docker container.

I have the IP of the container but when trying to connect I get the following error.

`All host(s) tried to query failed. First host tried, {ip}: DriverError: Connection timeout`

I'm trying to connect like this.

```
var client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['{ip}'], keyspace:'ks1'});

    client.connect(function (err) {
        assert.ifError(err);
      });
```

I don't know much about docker, so some help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got it working.

1. Cant connect to the container IP but to localhost.
2. I was missing parameters.

```
var client = new cassandra.Client(
    {contactPoints: ['127.0.0.1'], keyspace:'tfm',localDataCenter: 'datacenter1',}
);
```

This was the code that worked.